# go from one UIViewController to another without using navigation (segue) iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

In my program I have `UIViewController` which has two buttons, one is "signIN" and other is "register". When "Sign IN" button is pressed, it should go to next `viewController` without using segue and when "register" button is pressed, it should move to next `UIViewController` by using segue.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by not using a `segue`? If you only want to prevent a `push` transition, you can easily change the transition style (e.g.: `modal`).

Comment: want achieve nevigation by using Code no segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pushViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController%3aanimated%3a):

```
- (void)didPressButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way you wish to present your view controller you should choose between:

1. Pushing the new view controller onto the current Navigation controller

   `[self.navigationController pushViewController:someOtherViewController animated:YES];`
2. Present the new view controller modally

   `[self presentModalViewController:someOtherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`
3. Manually adding the new view controller onto the current view controller:

   `[self addChildViewController:childController];
   childController.view.frame = view.bounds;
   [view addSubview:childController.view]; 
   [childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
   // To remove:
   [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; 
   [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
   [self removeFromParentViewController];`

Comment: Regarding the adding as a child view controller - your missing some code, here is a more complete example with the correct order as described in Apples documentation:
[self addChildViewController:childController];
childController.view.frame = view.bounds;
[view addSubview:childController.view];
[childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
To Remove:
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
Child view controller is in fact the entire mechanism story boards are built on behind the scenes (with a combination of nav

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:yourPushedViewController animated:YES];
```